# Android code to alert when a specific bluetooth device is on

Tags: android, bluetooth, alert

I want to know how make a Bluetooth program with android, witch the main functionality is alert me when a specific Bluetooth device is on (by introducing on code for example the name of that device).

E.g. If my cell phone Bluetooth is on i want to be alert in my android program in another cell phone for example.

I try some programs but they gave me all the same, only discover new devices or connect to them.

Thanks

Comment: You can check if the specific device is found in the list of the discovered devices and then alert accordingly...

Comment: Hum how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mSpecificDevice` is the specific device you want to check.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Return Intent extra
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";
    private String mSpecificDevice = "my-device";


    // Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set result CANCELED in case the user backs out
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    }


    public void doDiscovery(View view) {
        doDiscovery();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    /**
     * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
     */
    private void doDiscovery() {

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (mSpecificDevice.equals(device.getName())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), device.getName() + " is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"
    android:onClick="doDiscovery"/>
```

Don't forget to add the following to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: The code works thanks so much, Its better than nothing and I'm grateful, but what this app does is when I click on check button show if its on or not mydevice. What i really want and i dont know how to do is, if mydevice is on without buttons, the app show a message telling me the device is on.

Comment: Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

instead of button calling doDiscovery you can use threading which call this methaod after every some seconds